# How To Find Specific Data From A Text File and Change It?

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to change this code to write it to a text file.

Basically I have to find the price of an item that was stored in the array 'List', each pointer contains an item code, description, price and discount.

I'm having two problems though, finding the item's price in the text file and than changing it by the user's input.

```
void DoSetItemPrice(void)
{
   

     int `searchCode` = 0;
    

    double changePrice = 0.00;
    

    cout << "Enter Code For Search: ";
    

    cin >> searchCode;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter Price Change: $";
        cin >> changePrice;
        cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
              if (List[i].HasCode(searchCode) == true)
             {
            List[i].SetPrice(changePrice);
             cout << "New Price: $" << List[i].GetDiscount();
        
         } else
            
            cout << "The Code You Entered Could Not Be Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the file writing part that you're actually facing an issue with? I just see values being set on a particular `List` item. Also, what's the format of the file that you're writing to?

Comment: The file is writing to List.dat. I'm having trouble starting it or how to go about it

Comment: `.dat` _usually_ indicates some binary file format. Are you trying to write the data in `List` array (is it an array?) to a file in binary format? Please share the expectations from your program and where you are stuck exactly.  `I'm having two problems though, finding the item's price in the text file and than changing it by the user's input.` Are you reading from a _text_ file and then trying to update the file back with a new value obtained from the user? Please try to explain the problem as you would to a friend. And that friend has no idea about C++, of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

i had this kind of situation before but my solution was kinda bad but here it is anyways,i don't know any pre defined functions in C++ that helps with string manipulation, but u can try entering a character before the price like 'ù' for example ,if the price is 100$ the string would become "ù100$" then based on that u can use a loop to check the text file u are reading and when ever u encounter the character 'ù' that means what comes after it is the price so u convert that part into numbers until u reach the '$' character which indicates the end of the price.

Comment: HasCode is not working with strings, how do I use it to find some symbol say @ from the file?